# Combine Two or More Private Sub in one worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have two private sub as below (maybe more) in one sheet. 
Each one works separately, but when I have both, only first one works. Could you please help me out.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("f6:G19, j6:m19, f22:G35, j22:j35, L22:M35")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If Not Target.MergeCells Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
    Else
        If IsEmpty(Target.Cells(1, 1)) Then Exit Sub
    End If

    Cancel = True
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Lastrow = Sheets("ShoppingCart").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Target.Cells(1, 1).Copy Sheets("ShoppingCart").Cells(Lastrow, 3)



End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick_B(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("h24:h25, h8:h9")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If Not Target.MergeCells Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
    Else
        If IsEmpty(Target.Cells(1, 1)) Then Exit Sub
    End If


    Cancel = True
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Lastrow = Sheets("ShoppingCart").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Target.Cells(1, 1).Copy Sheets("ShoppingCart").Cells(Lastrow, 3)
    Sheets("ShoppingCart").Cells(Lastrow + 1, 3).Value = "148H3124"


End Sub
```

thank you so much in advance.

Comment: the only differences between two codes are first and last row of the codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handlers have specific names, it isn't recognizing the second sub as an event handler it just considers that a sub that happens to have a name that looks similar to the first one. You can either rename both and then create a new event sub and call them from that or combine them into a single sub.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    dblclick_a target, cancel
    dblclick_b target, cancel
end sub

Private Sub dblclick_a(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("f6:G19, j6:m19, f22:G35, j22:j35, L22:M35")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If Not Target.MergeCells Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
    Else
        If IsEmpty(Target.Cells(1, 1)) Then Exit Sub
    End If

    Cancel = True
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Lastrow = Sheets("ShoppingCart").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Target.Cells(1, 1).Copy Sheets("ShoppingCart").Cells(Lastrow, 3)

End Sub

Private Sub dblclick_b(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("h24:h25, h8:h9")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If Not Target.MergeCells Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
    Else
        If IsEmpty(Target.Cells(1, 1)) Then Exit Sub
    End If


    Cancel = True
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Lastrow = Sheets("ShoppingCart").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Target.Cells(1, 1).Copy Sheets("ShoppingCart").Cells(Lastrow, 3)
    Sheets("ShoppingCart").Cells(Lastrow + 1, 3).Value = "148H3124"


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Nailed it :)